# Javafx Alert Dialog + HTML

Tags: html, javafx, dialog, formatting, alert

I'm working with the new JavaFX Alert class (Java 1.8_40) and trying to use HTML tags inside the exibition text, but no success so far. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setHeaderText("This is an alert!");
alert.setContentText("<html>Pay attention, there are <b>HTML</b> tags, here.</html>");
alert.showAndWait();
```

Would anyone know if it is really possible, and show me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't worked with the new `Alert` class much, but I am pretty sure the text properties do not support HTML formatting.

You could use a web view to display HTML-formatted text:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlertHTMLTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Show Alert");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText("This is an alert!");
            WebView webView = new WebView();
            webView.getEngine().loadContent("<html>Pay attention, there are <b>HTML</b> tags, here.</html>");
            webView.setPrefSize(150, 60);
            alert.getDialogPane().setContent(webView);;
            alert.showAndWait();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @James_D Having switched to Java 9 SDK, the WebView does not display inside the alert box, whereas with Java 8 SDK it did...